# Does istio rate limiting work for websocket connections?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, rate-limiting

Istio has rate limiting features in recent version. Does this also work when using websocket connections to the clients? See also [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13191).

Answer (score 1):

Istio rate limits do apply to websockets, however its not necessarily useful. Because websockets can be very long lived, the resources used for each request can vary hugely. Imagine you system runs happily at 1000 RPS with websockets that last 1 seconds but then requests increase to 1 minute in length - you go from 1000 concurrent requests to 60,000 concurrent requests at the same request rate.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, not sure though. I am looking for a possible alternative to the token bucket algorithm solution described in [this blog (as described in the second half)](https://blog.feathersjs.com/feathersjs-in-production-password-policy-and-rate-limiting-32c9874dc563), which implements rate-limiting for websockets at the application level. Could istio give a similar rate-limiting?

Comment: Yes it does. But fundementally my point is that rate-limiting might not be what you want

Comment: Can you maybe comment more on the fact that websockets contrary to HTTP verbs/methods do not have 'requests'? What you send is bits over the wire, so a black box from the point of view of istio, I think. So I doubt you can achieve meaningful rate-limiting for websocket using istio. A rate-limiting solution for websockets will need to be more intrusive to your code.

Comment: So in short: istio will not provide rate-limiting for websockets as described in the blog article, I think.